# My clickable jQuery drop-down menu does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I've made a clickable drop-down menu using JQuery.

The drop-down menu must work like:
1) 'a' dropdown toggle Click, 'a' dropdown menu visible
2) not('a' dropdown toggle and 'a' dropdown menu) === dropdownMenu is hide
3) setTimeOut is need(i'm really code is animation css)

I want multiple drop-down menus.

a, b, c, d...and "Z"

but my drop-down menu gives this problem:
1) a drop-down toggle click, after b drop-down toggle click === a drop-down is not hide
2) but this code not include document.closeset(I want to include dropdownToggle.click(function ()<<<

How can I go about to clear this issue?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```js
$(function(){  
 body = $('body');

  /* dropdown */
  var dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
      dropdownToggle = dropdown.find('.toggle'),
      dropdownMenu = dropdown.find('.menu'),
      checkDropdownOpen = 'close';
  
  dropdownToggle.click(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {      
      // setInitial
      var thisDropdown = $(this).parent('.dropdown'),
          thisDropdownToggle = $(this),
          thisDropdownMenu = $(this).next('.menu');

      // checkDropdownMenu = open
      if (!thisDropdownMenu.hasClass('open') && (thisDropdownMenu.attr('aria-hidden') === 'true' || thisDropdownMenu.attr('aria-hidden') === undefined)) {        
        // visible
        setTimeout(function() {
          checkDropdownOpen = 'open';
          thisDropdownMenu.addClass('open');
        }, 10);

        // attr change
        setTimeout(function() {
          thisDropdownMenu.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
        }, 218); 
      } else if (thisDropdownMenu.hasClass('open') && thisDropdownMenu.attr('aria-hidden') === 'false') {
        // visible
        setTimeout(function() {
          checkDropdownOpen = 'close';
          thisDropdownMenu.removeClass('open');
        }, 10);

        // attr change
        setTimeout(function() {
          thisDropdownMenu.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
        }, 218); 
      }
    })
  });
  
  /* dropdownClose() */
  function dropdownClose() {
    // toggle
    dropdownMenu.removeClass('open');

    // hidden, attr change
    setTimeout(function() {
      body.removeClass('account-open');
      dropdownMenu.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    }, 218);
  }
  
  /* document click */
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    // dropdown
    if (!$(e.target).closest(dropdown).length) {
      dropdownClose();
    }
  });
 });
```

```css
.dropdown .menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown .menu.open {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="toggle">button</button>
  <div class="menu">article</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="toggle">button</button>
  <div class="menu">article</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the existing code, you could add this line:

```
dropdownClose();
```

between these lines:

```
dropdownToggle.click(function() {
$(this).each(function() {
```

This will close the entire menu before opening the target sibling menu.

Another way to do the same thing:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').hide(250);
     $(this).next().show(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: hello.
sorry. my code is animation & addClass, removeClass.  

i'm want my code some edit..  

this code is good very simple, but not my system.

Comment: dropdownToggle.click(function() { <br>dropdownClose();<br>$(this).each(function() {  ///// this? i'm try this, fixed error. (but this code is i don't know good code. this code is good?